# Macro-Enabled File Stops Working And Crashes When Any Action Taken

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So this is strange to me, but I have a macro-enabled excel 2016 file. The only macro in the file is a `BeforeSave` event, which is stored in `ThisWorkbook`. After using the blank file once or twice, it gets to the point where opening the file and doing anything at all, like clicking `File` or `Developer` or entering data, causes excel to "Stop Working" and close.

Below is the `BeforeSave` event which is the only macro in this file (there are no modules or userforms, nothing else in `ThisWorkbook`).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Cancel = True

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pending").Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This basic macro event will work perfectly for a few times. Then after some data is in the file, the next time it is opened the issue will occur. This is the only excel file that experiences this crash, I can still open the original backup file with this macro that does not have data in it yet, and it will be okay.

I have tried opening the file in Safe Mode, and I have installed all the latest Microsoft Office updates.

Has anyone else experienced an issue like this? Does it have something to do with the `BeforeSave` event macro?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. Also, I have changed from editing the entire column to now finding the last used row and formatting that range excluding the header row.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Cancel = True

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pending").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pending").Range("I2:I" & Lastrow).NumberFormat = "@"
ThisWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you maybe have AutoSave running in the background? Also mixing ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook might be an issue … just educated guesses

Comment: There might be an issue in Column 9 if any data cant be converted to your number format, such as a header.

Comment: @ZackE & Mathieu, thank you both for these suggestions. I will definitely address the `ThisWorkbook` vs `ActiveWorkbook`, and I will make an adjustment to factor in the header. I'm not entirely sure how to determine is AutoSave is running in the background, but I thought the `EnableEvents = False` would stop that from occurring?

Comment: I have updated to use only `ThisWorkbook` and not `ActiveWorkbook`, and I have also factored in the header as @ZackE proposed. So far the issue has not reoccured. I will post an answer with the updated code based on the above comments and mark as answered. If this issue occurs again then I will post a new thread if I cannot figure it out on my own. Thank you both for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zack & GWD advised in the comments, I updated the VBA to factor in the header row and set all references to `ThisWorkbook` instead of including `ActiveWorkbook`. So far the error has not occurred again. If it does happen in the future, I will post a new question if I cannot solve the issue.

Here is the updated code for reference:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Cancel = True

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pending").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pending").Range("I2:I" & Lastrow).NumberFormat = "@"
ThisWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```